# In Rdl file visual studio , Tablix want to show first 10 records and then show to next 10 in new tablix

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting, rdlc, rdl

I am working in visual studio with rdl file , want to show first 10 records in tablix and then next 10 to another tablix table , This code is not working.
How I can show first 10 here and If I want to show next 10 records which expression I will use?
Thanks in Advance.
My DataSetName is "TestData".

```
<TablixMember>
                                <Group Name="Details2">
                                <GroupExpressions>
                                    <GroupExpression>Ceiling(RowNumber(nothing)/10)</GroupExpression>
                                </GroupExpressions>
                                </Group>
                                <PageBreak>
                                    <BreakLocation>Between</BreakLocation>
                                </PageBreak>
                            </TablixMember>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Following code working for me. On First Tablix where I want to show 10 records I used this.

                   <TablixMember>
                   <Group Name="Details3" />
                   <Visibility>
                    <Hidden>=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) &gt;10, False, True)</Hidden>
                  </Visibility>
                  </TablixMember>
```

And where I want to show next records I used following logic.

```
               <TablixMember>
               <Group Name="Details2" />
               <Visibility>
                 <Hidden>=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) &lt;11, False, True)</Hidden>
               </Visibility>
              </TablixMember>
```